# How can one use a ready made winform design template in a basic project?

Tags: c#, winforms

(Hopefully it's not a duplicate question)

I have a WinForm project (Visula Studio 2013 ; .Net Framework 4).

My windows and their controls are just dragged and dropped. I did not make any changes about the design (font, color, etc...). I only ajusted the alingments.

My question : is there a way to make my windows more appealing by "loading" a ready made template in the project ? Positions will be kept but the "design" will look better.

I saw this but it looked too complicated for a newb like me. https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/CustomDocument16492.aspx

Any suggestion of yours will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean a "skin" where the visual appearance of the controls/widgets changes, but their locations and behavior remain the same?

Comment: @Dai Hmmm never heard of that.  If the "skin" is also able to change fonts, colors, background colors,... and many more aspects of controls then yes I mean "skin".... But not "skin" of Visual Studio BUT "skin" of my custom forms

Comment: It sounds it like this is what you're looking for: https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/winforms/skins/

Comment: Thank You Dai. I'll look into it

Comment: Note that if you do want a quality, graphically-customized user-experience, I recommend against WinForms because it was never built with high-performance 2D graphics in mind: GDI is slow (even slower since Microsoft removed hardware-acceleration since Windows Vista). You should use WPF.

Answer (score 2):

Themes or skins for Winforms components produced by DevExpress, Telerik, Infragistic etc. applies only if you use their controls, too. If you are going to develop lots of Winform apps or even just one complex, I would strongly recommend to use vendor components - not just because of theming/skins, but you will get lots of controls which don't exist as native Winforms.

There are several options, some of them are even free - check for example this list: [Best Free Controls for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361271/best-free-controls-for-net)

You posted an interesting question, I've never thought of themes for native Winforms controls before, but I found this one few minutes ago - if it's of any help:
https://github.com/IgnaceMaes/MaterialSkin

Comment: Thank You Tom. I'll look into it